# Como atualizar um TreeView de diretórios em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nullpointerexception

Tenho um componente TreeViewMS (aquele com Seleção Multipla) listando os diretórios do sistema em um Form.

criei um evento no Form que quando for apertado F5, esse TreeView se atualize(caso tenha 
algum novo diretório no sistema ou não).

Ele até chega a atualizar normalmente, por em seguida é arremessado um `NullReferenceException` na TreeView MS.dll na classe inicial do programa (Program.cs)

segue código para carregar a TreeView.

```
private void LoadTreeView() {
   tvDirectories.Nodes.Clear();
   exArq.CreateDirectoryTree(tvDirectories);
}
```

eis a Excessão:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TreeViewMS.dll
Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.`

Método CreateDirectoryTree faz a busca dos diretórios do sistema e monta a arvore, acredito que ele não seja o problema mas segue o método:

```
public TreeViewMS.TreeViewMS CreateDirectoryTree(TreeViewMS.TreeViewMS treeView) {

    foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives()) {
        TreeNode rootDirectoryNode = new TreeNode();
        rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
        rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
        rootDirectoryNode.Text = drv.Name;

        switch (drv.DriveType) {

            case DriveType.Network:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NetworkDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NetworkDiskIcon;
                break;

            case DriveType.CDRom:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.CDDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.CDDiskIcon;
                break;

            case DriveType.Fixed:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.LocalDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.LocalDiskIcon;
                break;

            case DriveType.Removable:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.RemovalDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.RemovalDiskIcon;
                break;

        }

        bool isSystemDirectory = drv.Name.ToString() == Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);

        if (isSystemDirectory) {
            rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
            rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
        }

        rootDirectoryNode.Nodes.Add(String.Empty);

        treeView.Nodes.Add(rootDirectoryNode);
    }
    return treeView;

}
```

Eu suspeito que seja a maneira de limpar a TreeView que deva estar causando o erro.

Eu imagino que não deva ser, mas vou incluir também onde é expandido o nó:

```
private void tvDiretorios2_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) {
     TreeNode newNode = exArq.GetDirectoriesAndFilesNodes(e.Node);
}
```

e a função que busca esses diretorios

```
public TreeNode GetDirectoriesAndFilesNodes(TreeNode parentNode) {

    string nodePath = parentNode.FullPath + Constants.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(nodePath);
    parentNode.Nodes[0].Remove();
    try {

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in rootDirectory.GetDirectories()) {

            TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode();
            directoryNode.Text = dir.Name;
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(String.Empty);
            directoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DirectoryIcon;
            directoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DirectoryIcon;
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);

        }

        foreach (FileInfo file in rootDirectory.GetFiles()) {

            bool isExcel = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_EXCEL_X) || Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_EXCEL);

            bool isZipedFile = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_RAR) || Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_ZIP);

            bool isTextFile = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_TXT);

            TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode();
            fileNode.Text = file.Name;

            if (isExcel) {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ExcelFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ExcelFileIcon;
            } else if (isZipedFile) {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ZipedFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ZipedFileIcon;
            } else if (isTextFile) {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.TextFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.TextFileIcon;
            } else {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.GenericFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.GenericFileIcon;
            }

            parentNode.Nodes.Add(fileNode);
        }

    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        TreeNode errorNode = new TreeNode();
        errorNode.Text = "Acesso Negado";
        errorNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NoPermissionIcon;
        errorNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NoPermissionIcon;
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(errorNode);
    } catch (IOException) {
        TreeNode errorNode = new TreeNode();
        errorNode.Text = "O Dispositivo não está pronto";
        errorNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DriverNotReady;
        errorNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DriverNotReady;
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(errorNode);
    }

    return parentNode;
}
```

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Seria interessante você postar o código do método `BuscarDiretorios`.

Comment: inserido amigo @jbueno

Comment: Notei que você faz o Cast da classe derivada **TreeViewMS** de volta para **TreeView**. Suponho que você esteja trabalhando com [esta classe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2756/C-TreeView-with-multiple-selection) mas, de qualquer forma, não seria melhor adaptar seus métodos, como **CreateDirectoryTree()** e outros, para trabalharem com o tipo da classe derivada TreeViewMS? Acho arriscado usar a interface da classe mãe, porque podemos acabar usando métodos de **TreeView** que foram sobrepostos (_overrides_) ou sombreados (_shadows_) por implementações específicas em **TreeViewMS**.

Comment: @VbobCat fiz as alterações correspondentes aqui e atualizei na pergunta também, obrigado por notar esses erros, porém continua sem funcionar, em meus testes, eu acesso um diretório pelo programa, crio uma pasta nova fora dele, atualizo o TreeView e volto a esse diretório, porém, assim que eu crio a nova pasta, a exception já é arremessada, antes mesmo de eu atualizar.

Comment: A exception vem na hora em que você cria a pasta via sistema operacional? Você tem no seu projeto algum objeto que monitora alterações nos diretórios, por exemplo um [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Sim! depois de criar via sistema operacional. não uso o FileSystemWatcher (não conhecia inclusive), mas não consigo imaginar onde adicionar ele nessa situação. a Arvore é criada pelo DirectoryInfo.

Comment: Creio que sem usar um FileSystemWatcher, não se está consumindo eventos gerados diretamente pelo sistema operacional. Em que instante exatamente você tem a exceção? Logo que cria a pasta nova no Windows Explorer, ou quando retorna ao seu programa e tenta usar o TreeView? Se for esse segundo caso, o que me parece é que a execução começa no manipulador do evento BeforeExpand, e encontra algum objeto (talvez interno) que se tornou "null". Qual o escopo da variavel **newnode** em `private void tvDiretorios2_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)`? Por que ela é definida duas vezes?

Comment: então, assim que eu volto para o programa e o TreeView é exibido é arremessada a exceção. a Variavel newNode tem escopo de classe (o form que usa o evento BeforeExpand), vou verificar se ele é usado em outro método, se não for, deixarei ele dentro do BeforeExpand, quanto a ser definido duas vezes, vou verificar também e posto uma atualização.

Comment: atualizado @VBobCat contudo o erro persiste, mas agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: Prezado, não trabalho com .NET, mas no construtor da classe LoadTreeView, você tem certeza que os objetos tvDirectories e exArq estão instanciados? Ao depurar o código, o que acontece? Parece ser alguma coisa de ciclo de vida do controle (objeto visual). Aliás, vc devolve um objeto TreeView? Meio esquisito isso, pois você está sobrescrevendo a instancia e as referências podem ficar totalmente fora de contexto. Por que simplesmente não devolve somente a hierarquia dos nós e recebe como entrada a referência da TreeView? Entende?

Comment: Afinal, me parece que está faltando isto  tvDirectories = exArq.CreateDirectoryTree(tvDirectories); no construtor. Você está devolvendo uma instância de TreeView...

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme, para te ajudar a identificar onde está o erro, voce pode incluir nos seus códigos um try...catch, assim você consegue identificar onde está o erro. voce pode colocar um breakpoint no throw.

Usando o breakpoint você pode avaliar toda a cadeia da exceção e ver onde está o erro.

```
private void LoadTreeView()
{
    try
    {
        tvDirectories.Nodes.Clear();
        exArq.CreateDirectoryTree(tvDirectories);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda Alexandre, essa função foi desnecessária para meu sistema e entreguei sem ela. obrigado mesmo assim.